# Need VBA code that retrieves sumproduct of particular rows and columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm wondering if someone can write me a VBA Code that retrieves the "sumproduct" of particular cells and columns. Here I have a screenshot of what I'm requesting.

[image]

To explain what the code does: it finds particular text that matches the words "ABC TOT", "EFG TOT", and "XYZ TOT" in **Column A** PAIRED WITH a particular text matching the words "THIS TITLE" in a particular column (I'm using Column C for this example) and retrieves the "total sum" of those paired words. So it will mean:

"ABC TOT" = 6

"EFG TOT" = 9

"XYZ TOT" = 6

Which means: 6 + 9 + 6 = 21

"**21**" is the resulting answer that I want input into a new cell. I can't just do **C5 + C10 + C15** because this is a spreadsheet with hundreds of rows & columns and the location of all the numbers change every day. One day the numbers in C5 are going to end up in H7 (etc.) and that will be a problem. So this is why I need VBA Code to automate the task for me and retrieve the resulting answer based on specific row and column text alone. I made a diagram below that you can copy/paste.

```
       NOTTHISTITLE THISTITLE NOTTHISTITLE
A                 0         1            0
B                 1         0            4
C                 2         5            1
ABC TOT           3         6            5

E                 0         0            1
F                 2         2            1
G                 2         7            0
EFG TOT           4         9            2

X                 1         3            4
Y                 0         1            0
Z                 1         2            3
XYZ TOT           2         6            7
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick by calling it either directly as a formula in Excel `=SumOnCondition(A1, "THISTITLE", "ABC TOT", "EFG TOT", "XYZ TOT")` or calling it from a `Sub` in VBA. Note you can specify an unlimited number of rows to match at the end of the function call.

```
Function SumOnCondition(StartCell As Range, ColumnName As String, ParamArray RowNames() As Variant) As Double
    
    Dim ColumnFound As Boolean
    Dim ColumnNr As Long
    ColumnNr = 0
    ' Find the column number for ColumnName
    Do While Not (ColumnFound)
        ColumnNr = ColumnNr + 1
        If StartCell.Offset(0, ColumnNr - 1).Value = ColumnName Then
            ColumnFound = True
        End If
    Loop
    
    ' Add all the matching RowNames
    Dim RowFound As Boolean
    Dim RowNr As Long
    RowNr = 1
    Dim RowName As Variant
    For Each RowName In RowNames
        Do While Not (RowFound)
            RowNr = RowNr + 1
            If StartCell.Offset(RowNr - 1, 0).Value = RowName Then
                RowFound = True
                SumOnCondition = SumOnCondition + StartCell.Offset(RowNr - 1, ColumnNr - 1)
            End If
        Loop
        
        ' reset to defaults:
        RowFound = False
        RowNr = 1
    Next RowName
    
End Function
```

## Usage:

### 1. You can call this function from a cell in your workbook:

[image: Usage in Excel cell]

### 2. You can call this function from another `Sub`:

```
Sub RunSumOnCondition()

    ActiveCell.Value = SumOnCondition(Range("A1"), "THISTITLE", "ABC TOT", "EFG TOT", "XYZ TOT")

End Sub
```